# When might I NOT want to call Session.Abandon() on LogOut?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm troubleshooting authentication errors showing up in a log (anti-forgery token errors, in case you're wondering). One thing I notice is that there is no call to Session.Abandon() in the LogOut method which I would normally expect to see there.

I don't know that this is necessarily a problem, but now I'm wondering if there is any legitimate reason why one might not want to call it when the user logs out? I would like to add it to rule out it being the source of any issues, but also want to make sure there are no legitimate reasons why it might have been excluded to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons not to use Session.Abandon() method. It is totally depend on the application requirement. For example, in the following scenarios you should not call the Session.Abandon().

1. **When supporting multiple authentication providers**, do not abandon
   the session on logout as the user may still be logged in with
   another provider.
2. If using **session data in background tasks**, calling
   Session.Abandon() on Logout can prevent tasks from completing and
   cause errors.
3. If **SessionStateMode is Off**, calling Session.Abandon() is unnecessary
   as it would have no effect.